# Epoch 1970 in Windsws system (Python)

Tags: python, windows, epoch

On UNIX systems, the epoch is 1 January 1970. On Windows systems, the epoch is 1 January 1601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).
However, when I run the Python code `time.gmtime(0)` in a Windows system, I got:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

Why is it so?

Comment: The article you linked says: "`1 January 1970: Unix Epoch aka POSIX time, used by Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS), and programming languages: ..., Python, ...`". However Python's own [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) says that "`To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at time.gmtime(0)`". So it seems that the Python implementation you're using has a platform-independent epoch.

Comment: According to Python's [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b49263b698993cad2b8aaddc55cdeaa678412b30/Python/pytime.c#L1190), it's using the C function [`gmtime_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) for Windows, and `gmtime_r` for other systems. So it seems that the C compiler that was used to build your Python version used a UNIX-like implementation for those functions. Maybe it's that way in like `gcc` versus Visual C or something like that.

Comment: Oh also if you do `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)`, the bottom line should show something like `[GCC 9.3.0]`, aka the compiler used. That's how you can determine which specific implementation of those functions were used in your Python version.